# Is there an equivalent of JSF @ViewScope in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the application I'm developing in ASP MVC 3 I have the following scenario. I have some properties of the model that I wanna use after the page makes a request, however when the post request is done they arrive as null since they are not bound to any control in the view form.

For what I've read this is the expected behaviour of ASP MVC and people recommend to use a @Html.HiddenFor() to be able to receive them, but I don't want this information to be available to user in case he selects "View source" from the browser.

In JSF I remember that you could use the @ViewScope annotation for this scenario, but is there something similar in ASP MVC? For what I've read saving them in the ViewData property will not work either and I do not want to use the Session because this properties will only be relevant in this particular view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may be looking for something like TempData.

You can read about it here:
http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/

A more recent post can be found here:
http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/controller-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3/