# How to pass value from web form to another web form?

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody tell me how to pass a value from one web form to another web form without using a query string and session?

Comment: `connection string` means? could you please specific in your terms?

Comment: @Knvn: I think he meant query strings....

Comment: Ya Knvn its query string.. Sry for mistake...

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the Values over different pages via QueryString like:

```
Response.Redirect("yourNextpage.aspx?identifier=DesiredValue");
```

On your next page you can retrieve the value like this:

```
Request.QueryString["identifier"];
```

Other Preferred way would be [Server.Transer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Postbackurl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx).

Refer [this link](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx) for various possible ways.

Comment: if it is possible without using query string??

Answer (score 3):

there are several ways you can pass parameters between pages.

1. Using a Query String
2. Getting Post Information from the Source Page
3. Using Session State
4. Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page
5. Getting Control Information from the Source Page in the Same Application

for more detail visit followng link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Querystring in this case:

```
Page.Response.Redirect("show.aspx?id=1");
```

And then read it on the other end:

```
int id = Page.Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `PostBackURL`, ex:

```
PostBackUrl="~/result.aspx"
```

and on `result.cs` (Page Load)

```
lblEmployeeNumber.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["txtEmployeeNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Session:**

For example you login the system and your id is 123123123.

```
string userid = 123123123; 


Session["userid"] = userid;
```

When you go another page/pages your session is alive when your session timeout.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="1250"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're looking for is something like the flash-, view- or conversation scope in Java EE and Ruby on Rails.

For ASP.NET you could perhaps take a look at this one: [Is there an equivalent of JSF @ViewScope in ASP MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279971/is-there-an-equivalent-of-jsf-viewscope-in-asp-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

depends on type and how much information you wish to transfer. for instance, if you want to transfer some variable (strings or integer values) you consider to use querystring (you can found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring) major information). for instance, if you want to transfer typed objects (class instance) you consider to use session (you can found [here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) major information).

Comment: Answers need contain enough informations that they stay useful even if the links die. Please read [answer].