# Dynamically generate a label by clicking a button on another webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am developing a web application on ASP.Net and the language being used is C#.
I want to dynamically generate a label on WebForm 2 when clicked on a specific button on WebForm 1.
I am a beginner and I do not have much coding experience.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of your code to give a better example? Are these WebForms on the same page or two different pages?

Comment: They are 2 different pages.

Comment: I need to fire a command with the on click event on a button to generate a label on another WebForm

Comment: That means clicking a button on the first page will redirect to the second page. You could include a query parameter to the second WebForm so it will generate the label
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967584/how-to-pass-value-from-web-form-to-another-web-form